# Cannot use \usepackage with custom document class "ws-srl"

Tags: document-classes

I am having problems with `\usepackage` using a custom document class. An error was returned whenever `\usepackage` was used. Please help me.

```
\documentclass{ws-srl}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
```

The error returned is:

```
 "! LaTeX Error: \RequirePackage or \LoadClass in Options Section.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help...."
```

I added `\usepackage{caption}` in the class file. But it returned another error

```
 "! LaTeX Error: Command \captionbox already defined.Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... ...ption@withoptargs{\caption@ibox\@gobble}}"
```

The class file and tex file can be found in the following link

[Tex and class file](https://goo.gl/s7SHur)

The complete folder is given below

[Tex folder](https://goo.gl/wVfGY5)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I don't get the first error, only the second one; from what I can see, the class is not compatible with the `caption` package: it happens for several custom classes. This one is particularly nasty, I'm afraid. Use it only if you're really forced to.

Comment: I fear, the class file is too old and too unmaintained.

Comment: @egreg Do you want to take any action here?

Comment: @Johannes_B Answered

Answer (score 2):

The second error is raised because the `caption` package is not compatible with the `ws-srl` class. It's a class designed for submissions to World Scientific publications and *they* decide the format.

The first error is probably due to an outdated version of the class, as the one I downloaded does not produce it.

Comment: Another one off the list :-)